# How to show vectors are linearly independent?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

Suppose $A_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R)$ and $\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}$ are non zero vectors in $\mathbb R^3$, such that:
$$A\vec{u}=0, A\vec{v}=\vec{v} \text{ and } Aw = 2\vec{w}.$$

How to show that the vectors $\vec{u}, \vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ are linearly independent?

Comment: Notice that $u,v,$ and $w$ are eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: @Mnifldz: $0$ is usually not considered an eigenvalue.

Comment: @gary I've heard 0 as a vector not being considered an eigenvector, but there are tons of nontrivial cases with 0 being an eigenvalue. Can you defend that claim with any sources?

Comment: @walkar: I $0$ is an eigenvalue then {$v: Av=0v=0$} is the kernel . What cases are there for $0$ being an eigenvalue?

Comment: @Gary. Take $M = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)$ as a $2\times 2$ real matrix. Then it has eigenvalues 0 and 1.

Comment: @walkar In fact, using your $M$ and any orthogonal $P$ we have $PMP^T$ has eigenvalues $0$ and $1$.

Comment: OK, I may have written too fast and mixed $0$ as an eigenvector /eigenvalue. My bad.

Comment: Yes, you are all right, my bad. $0$ is an eigenvalue precisely when the matrix is not invertible.

Answer (score 2):

By contradiction. Assume they are linearly dependent, then there exist $A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}$ not all zero such that
$$C\vec{u} + A\vec{v} + B\vec{w} = \vec{0}.$$
Since the constants are not all zero, one of them is non-zero, say $C$ (argument would be similar for $A \ne 0$ or $B \ne 0$). Then notice that $a = -A/C$ and $b = -B/C$ satisfy
$$\vec{u} = a\vec{v} + b\vec{w}.$$
Now compute $A\vec{v}$ directly. Can you finish the proof?

Comment: Ermmm not really quite understand. @gt6989b

Comment: @brotherkase What does it mean for $\vec{u}, \vec{v}, \vec{w}$ to be *linearly dependent*? Use the definition to show the relationship in the answer for some non-zero real numbers $a$ and $b$. Then, compute $$A \vec{u} = A \left(a \vec{v} + b\vec{w}\right)$$ and simplify this expression using the relationship you posted in your answer.

Comment: @gt6989b Are the vectors $\mathbf u = [1,1,1], \mathbf v = [1,0,0], \mathbf w = [2,0,0]$ linearly dependent? If so, can  you find corresponding $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @Kaster not sure this is intended for me. Add the brotherkase tag if not. Certainly, $\vec{v}, \vec{w}$ are linearly dependent and suitable constant are easily found.

Comment: @gt6989b it is intended to you :) Question is, is the tripe $\mathbf u, \mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$ LD, not just the last two.

Comment: @Kaster yes. If $\vec{v}, \vec{w}$ are LD, so is any other collection of vectors with these included. For your case, let $a = 0, b = -2$ and $c = 1$ and note that $$a\vec{u} + b \vec{v} + c \vec{w} = \vec{0}.$$ The constants in the definition of LD cannot be *all zero*, but some of them can be zero at will.

Comment: @gt6989b exactly. You should admit that last definition of LD is broader than the one you provided above. I was just wondering why aren't you using that.

Comment: @Kaster I did not use the full definition, what I used is a direct consequence of the definition...

Comment: @gt6989b well, I'm confused now. The one you're using doesn't cover all possibilities for the vectors to be LD. In particular, there are no $a$ and $b$ such that $u = a v + b w$ for the $u,v$ and $w$ I provided above.

Comment: @Kaster You're right, but this case is different since they are eigenvalues of the same matrix. I will change the answer in a sec

Comment: @Kaster done, please look again...

Comment: @gt6989b Looks good to me :)

Comment: $A$ as a constant is not the best choice when $A$ is also the matrix:)

Answer (score 1):

An eigenspace associated to a given eigenvalue $\lambda$ is a subspace. But $w$ is in the eigenspace for $\lambda =2$, $v$ is in the eigenspace for $\lambda =1$ and $v$ is in the kernel of $A$, which is also a subspace. Eigenvectors associated to different eigenvalues are independent. Ultimately:

$c_1w+c_2v+c_3u=0 \rightarrow A(c_1w+c_2v+c_3u)= 2c_1w+ c_2u=0$  is a linear combination of eigenvectors in different eigenspaces that equals $0$ , so we must have $c_1=c_2=0$. From $c_3u=0$ we get $c_3=0$ and so $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @Winther: Thanks, just edited.